# WiX Burn custom bootstrapper: how to preserve a value stored in e.Result?

Tags: wix, burn

When a user click `Cancel` button in my bootstrapper UI, I store `Result.Cancel` to `e.Result` in `Progress` event handler. But when `ApplyComplete` is fired, the value of `e.Result` in its handler is not `Result.Cancel`, but `Result.None`.

How can I preserve the value of `e.Result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.Result` is different for every callback, you can't preserve it.  The error from `ApplyComplete` should be 0x80070642 (which is the HRESULT form of the Win32 error code `ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT`) if you returned `Result.Cancel` from a callback.  You should check for that error code.

Comment: Now, I have switch-case statement in `ApplyComplete` callback that shows appropriate (last) dialog based on the value of `e.Result`. Is this meaningless? (As you said above, its value in `ApplyComplete` callback is always `Result.None`) Should I depend on my own state variable that indecates cancel, error, ..., etc?

Comment: @sky I recommend using the `Status` from the `ApplyCompleteEventArgs`, but you can use your own state variable if you like that better.

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I know the meaning of the value of the `Status` from `ApplyCompleteEventArgs`?

Comment: @sky It's an HRESULT.  Basically, if it's less than 0 then it's an error.  0 is success, and 0x80070642 is cancel.